# How to get max score of answers to a question by each user

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have these 2 models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # other fields

class Answer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    score = models.IntegerField()
```

each user can answer a question multiple times.

Imagine I have these answers:

```
{
     "user": 1,
     "question": 1,
     "score": 50
},
{
     "user": 1,
     "question": 1,
     "score": 100
},
{
     "user": 2,
     "question": 1,
     "score": 100
},
{
     "user": 2,
     "question": 1,
     "score": 200
},
{
     "user": 2,
     "question": 2,
     "score": 100
},
{
     "user": 2,
     "question": 2,
     "score": 200
}
```

I want a query to give me this result:

```
{
     "user": 1,
     "question": 1,
     "max_score": 100
},
{
     "user": 2,
     "question": 1,
     "max_score": 200
},
{
     "user": 2,
     "question": 2,
     "max_score": 200
}
```

I want all of the max scores of each user to each answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from django.db.models import Max

Answer.objects.all().values("user", "question").annotate(score=Max("score"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to achieve your goal with Django ORM, but you can do it with RawSQL

```
Answer.objects.raw("""
select a1.* from answer a1 LEFT JOIN answer a2
    ON (
        a1.user_id = a2.user_id and a1.score < a2.score
    )
where a2.user_id isnull
""")
```

Explanation: you get only records from you table, that have no bigger `score` from same table for each user.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not allowed to use raw queries.